# How can I HyperLink to another model using the property of a ForeignKey in a serializer

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm trying to generate a link to the user when serializing a snippet (i.e. my model).

The model already has a foreign key that links to the user who creates this snippet, but I don't know how to link `HyperlinkedRelatedField` to that user.

The code is based on django-rest-framework's official tutorial 05, you can [find it here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/)

serializers.py:

```py
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="rest-serial:snippet-detail")

    # TODO: Link to the user
    # Currently this would use the snippet's pk as the user's pk
    owner = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name="rest-serial:user-detail")

    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner',
                  'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style']
```

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Snippet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='snippets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    ...
```

I was thinking about something like

```py
owner = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name="rest-serial:user-detail", queryset=User.objects.filter(id='owner.id'))
```

but apparently that's not how django works. Can anyone point me a direction?

Comment: Seen [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield)? What you're doing should work, you might need to add `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` depending on how your url patterns are setup.

Comment: @dirkgroten the problem is, `id` field is a integer, I can't use `id="owner.id"`, I don't know how to access owner.id to make django happy